# php: variable in object not working

Tags: php, variables, object

using a variable for an object but i cant access the object, you can see my code below where i tried it with

```
 $score = $score[1];
    $score = ''.$score.'';
    $score_data = $data_json2->$score;

    if (!empty($score_data)) {return ja;}
    else {return nein;}
```

tried several things but dont know where my fault is, please, need advice with my code so it works

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do here and what fails

Comment: So you are trying to get the object that is the value of $score.  Wouldn't it be $data_json2->{$score}; ?

Comment: Do you realize that `$score` is entirely different from `$data_json2->score`? Note that it's `$object->variable`, not `$object->$variable` (no second $).

Comment: Why are you returning `ja` and `nein`? Are these constants?

Comment: @Ryan those two are equivalent.

Comment: Line 2 does nothing, don't you maean $score = "'$score'"; or $score = "'" . $score . "'"; Even with that I don't see why you would be quoting it then using it to get a property

Comment: i want to return a vlaue when its true or false  like "false" and "true"

Comment: but score_data is always "nein" returning

Comment: @tandu I was pretty sure wrapping $score with {} would cause it to evaluate the variable and use that as the object's variable.

Comment: Are you sure a property of whatever $score is actually what you think it is in the $data_json2 object?

Comment: i use it for preg_replace_callback so score[1] stores the results of my templating function  so when in my template {test} then data_son2->test = "Testvalue from JSON String Object"

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple things wrong with your code.

```
$score      = $score[1];
//$score    = ''.$score.''; <- useless, you add nothing to the start and end
$score_data = $data_json2->{$score}; // I suppose this is what you're trying to do

if (!empty($score_data)) {return 'ja';}
else {return 'nein';} // unless ja and nein are constants, you need to add quotes
```

The problem is probably doing `$data_json2->$score` instead of `$data_json2->{$score}`.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
$score_data = $data_json2->{$score[1]};

return empty($score_data) ? false : true;
```

Comment: `$var->$prop` and `$var->{$prop}` are functionally identical. The latter syntax exists to remove ambiguity in some cases, e.g. `$var->{$prop->something}`. I can only assume the `''.$score.''` was for casting the numeric score as a string.

Comment: You can validly do $foo->$bar, it registers the same as $foo->{$bar} read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: $score = $score[1];
  $score_data = $data_json2->{$score};
  if (!empty($score_data)) {return "ja";}
  else {return "nein";}  it always says "nein"

Answer (score 0):

Without having any idea what `$score` or `$data_json2` contain, I can only suggest using `var_dump()` on those two variables and verifying that they have the structure you believe them to have.

Comment: score is a string  data_json2 is an object with elements like eg apple  so when score = apple it should retun ja but it doesnt?